# Model validation using db value in Range

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two tables, Campaign and Advert with a one to many relationship. During Advert creation, the user selects a pre-defined Campaign to which the Advert will belong. A Campaign has an RRP money field and the Advert has a SalePrice money field. What I'm after is a way to ensure that the submitted Advert.SalePrice is >= the chosen Campaigns RRP.

Can this be done in the model? Something along the lines of this in the Advert_Validation? Is it even possible to fill the values of a Range with method calls?

```
[Range(0, getCampaignRRP(), ErrorMessage = "Value must be equal or greater than the Campaign RRP")]
public double SalePrice { get; set; }
```

Or do I need to check at the Controller level? All help appreciated!

Thanks all,

Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the new `Remote` attribute. Basically it calls an action and returns true or false. Here's a [link](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/01/04/ASPNETMVC3RemoteValidationTutorial.aspx) to an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit the RangeAttribute class and use that instead.

```
public class MyRange: RangeAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            //Your validation here.
            return MyValidateRange(value, 0, getCampaignRRP());
        }
    }

[MyRange(0, 0, ErrorMessage = "Value must be equal or greater than the Campaign RRP")]
public double SalePrice { get; set; }
```